# Where are the resources' IDs?

Tags: android

Android will allocate ids for each pics in the res/drawable directory. Where are they? 
I want to dynamically choose one pic form the pool and show it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in the res/drawable folder.

If the file name is demo.png, then they can be accessed by R.drawable.demo

If you want to access a random drawable, store all the resource identifiers in a Integer ArrayList, and programatically generate a random function using Random(), and get that particular item from the arraylist. Then you'll have a random drawable every time.

Answer (score 0):

Autogenerated ids are in the gen file, but not advisable to use them. It would be better to use the filenames directly through some predefined array of R.drawable.filename and randomly pick them.

Answer (score 0):

There IDs are stored in the R.java file, but you cannot edit it, as your changes are over written each time.

You can also access resources by name, which may be a viable approach to solving your problem if you know the names of the resources or can derive them according to some pre-defined naming scheme. (for example images are named in the sequence `image1`, `image2` and so on.

You have to map the name to the identifier using the [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of the `Resources` class.

```
String name = "resource" + rng.nextInt(count);
int resource = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", "com.package");
```

The documentation for this method says:

> Note: use of this function is
>   discouraged. It is much more efficient
>   to retrieve resources by identifier
>   than by name.

This is true but need not be a problem if you are doing it in code that isn't performance sensitive.

Alternatively, if you don't mind listing the resources in XML, you could create [a typed array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) that you can then randomly select from.

Comment: If I list all the pics in the layout XML, all the pics will show up.

Comment: what I want to do is choosing one pic via GridView, and then show the chosen pic in activity 2. My idea is using Intent carrying the index of the chosen pic, and then I use the index to determine which pic should be shown in activity 2. Could this way work? And if I list all the pics in layout XML, all of them will show up when program is running. But I just want to see the one I choose in the gallery.